# How to remove certain values before plotting data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using python for the first time. I have a csv file with a few columns of data: location, height, density, day etc... I am plotting height (i_h100) v density (i_cd) and have managed to constrain the height to values below 50 with the code below. I now want to constrain the values on the y axis to be within a certain 'day' range say (85-260). I can't work out how to do this.

```
import pandas 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
data.plot(kind='scatter',x='i_h100',y='i_cd')
plt.xlim(right=50)
```

Comment: have a look at [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html).

Comment: I need to remove the data from the day column so that it is not included in my plot, clip seems to reassign the values

Comment: If you only want to plot height vs density, maybe you want to do `data[['height', 'density']].plot(kind='scatter',x='i_h100',y='i_cd')`. BTW, it is very difficult to answer a question if you don't provide some sample input and desired outputs. For example, I have to now guess what you column names are. I recommend you edit your question to add this detail.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the info, this is my first time on here so will try to make it easier next time!

Comment: @HeatherKay no problem, I also recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example but providing sample inputs and desired outputs make it much easier to understand that intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` to subset data going into graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some dummy data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,365,20),
                   'b':np.random.rand(20),
                   'c':np.random.rand(20)})

# all data: plot of 'b' vs. 'c'
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='b', y='c')
plt.show()

# use .loc to subset data displayed based on value in 'a'
# can also use .loc to restrict values of 'b' displayed rather than plt.xlim
df.loc[df['a'].between(85,260) & (df['b'] < 0.5)].plot(kind='scatter', x='b', y='c')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's not actually the data on the y axis I need to limit. On the y axis is density, I need to remove the data from certain days before plotting height v density

Comment: In that case, use `.loc` to subset the data by a third variable before plotting. Will edit the comment shortly.

Comment: so df.loc[(df['c'].between(85,260)].plot(kind='scatter',x='a',y='b')

Comment: You'll need to edit per your variables (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but that approach should work.

Comment: Note also that this does not *remove* any records from your dataframe. It merely plots a subset of those records. So subsequent operations on the dataframe will use the entire range. If you want to remove records entirely, you can use `.drop`.

Comment: @HeatherKay Glad it worked. If that's the case, it would be good to accept the answer provided. Cheers.